# LINQ to List<T> gives an error

Tags: c#, linq

i have class like below

```
class Person
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Surname{get;set;}
  public int Age{get; set;}
}
```

I have a list like this

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
```

Then there is a method

```
public Person SelectPerson(string name)
{
  var q = from p in persons where p.Name==name select p;
  return (Person)q;
}
```

But it gives an error like this
**Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[PrsLst.Person]' to type 'PrsLst.Person'.**
SO what is the problem and can u help me to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public Person SelectPerson(string name)
{
  var q = from p in persons where p.Name==name select p;
  return q.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Note that the `FirstOrDefault` method will just take the first item, and ignore any following, so if you would have duplicates it would simply pick one item arbitrary, and you wouldn't know that something was wrong. Also, the return type of the method is already `Person`, so it doesn't need any casting.

Comment: Good point about the cast, it has been removed. As for the use of FirstOrDefault and the necessity to check for duplicates, I think you're going beyond the scope of the question. Your assumptions about the requirements of the SelectPerson function are reasonable but not confirmed by the question as stated.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
public Person SelectPerson(string name)
{
  var q=(from p in persons where p.Name==name select p).FirstOrDefault();;
  return q;
}
```

Comment: this will give error. you are returning `var` instead of `Person`.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - There is nothing wrong and it wont complain.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: No, it won't. The type of the variable happens to be `Person`. There is no "var" type, the compiler determines what type to use.

Comment: I haven't tried such code but to the naked eye it seems you are returning var, which can be anything and not just Person. I know var type is set as the initiated type, but you can easily replace the query for some other type and it won't show anything during compilation

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: The type is determined during compilation, so if you change the query to return a different type that doesn't match the return type of the method, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: hmm....i was reading that only :-) ...don't know about the intellisense though....will write this in VS and check for myself

Comment: Although, the `var` keyword shouldn't even be used here, as the type is known and easy to specify.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the result of the query is a collection of items, even if the collection happens to only contain one item.

Use the `Single` method to get the single item out of the collection. It also verifies that the collection actually only contains only one item, and throws an exception if it doesn't.

As the collection is known to contain `Person` items, you don't have to cast the result to `Person`.

```
public Person SelectPerson(string name) {
  var q = from p in persons where p.Name==name select p;
  return q.Single();
}
```

The `Single` method will also throw an exception if the result is empty. If you rather want to return `null` in that case, you can use the `SingleOrDefault` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Person SelectPerson(string name)
{
    Person q = (from p in persons where p.Name==name 
               select p).FirstOrDefault();
    return q;
}
```